# getNodeSet returns zero output

Tags: xml, r

I've got the xml accessible by [this link](http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=Google9b4-b128-4ff7-8843-a2bceed9e4b&OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&categoryId=60437&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&paginationUnput.pageNumber=100). I'm trying to convert them to the dataset in R.

I use XML package for this.
First,

```
d <- xmlParse("v1.xml") ## name of the downloaded file, tried link above as well
```

and then

```
t <- getNodeSet(d,'//itemId')
```

to apply the result to `xmlToDataFrame` function. But `getNodeSet` returns no output. I tried different `xmlPaths` and full path as well

```
("//findCompletedItemsResponse/searchResult/item/itemId")
```

but it doesn't work.

Please, advice me on whether I use wrong syntax or there are any problems with my xml file.

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with namespaces. Use

```
getNodeSet(d, "//*[local-name() = 'itemId']")
or
getNodeSet(d, "//x:itemId", namespaces = c(x = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"))
```